# OS X YOSEMITE, LOGITECH mouse M510 scroll wheel moves very little if do only1 click

Tags: macos

If you turn the scroll wheel slowly; just one or two clicks at a time then the screen barely moves.

You have to spin it more to get the screen to scroll significantly, and then it's difficult to control how much.

Comment: So...? What should it be doing?

Comment: cpast - any more questions? Did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure how far each scroll input from your mouse goes, it's called *Scrolling Speed*.

Open *System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Mouse Options > Scrolling Speed*.

[image: screenshot of Scrolling Speed settings in OSX 10.10]

You may also be finding the scrolling with inertia to be confusing, you should try turning off inertia from that same menu.

Comment: Hi Doc. When I press "mouse options", this is the only thing I have: http://puu.sh/df3Dz/ea2dc2e453.png